# Linux and Windows initialise structs differently

Tags: c, struct, malloc

While switching from linux back to windows, I noticed that my code stopped working. Using the trusty debugger, I found that structs were being initialised differently.

```
typedef struct base{
    struct item * first;
}BASE;

typedef BASE *SPACE;

...

hashmap = malloc(sizeof(SPACE *) * length);
hashSpaceSize = length;
```

Look at this code for example (hid extra code to keep it tidy, also ignore *struct item* it's not useful here). Let's say that length is 3. In Linux, when I check the debugger, I see that:

```
hashmap[0] = NULL;
hashmap[1] = NULL;
hashmap[2] = NULL;
```

Because I did not initialise the BASEs, I only initialised the fact that there is an array of them. However, in Windows, I see that all of the BASES are initialised. Not only that, but all of the ITEMs within the BASEs are initialised as well.

However, if I, for example, immediately afterwards add this line:
`hashmap[0]->first = NULL`, I end up with a `SIGSEGV` error that I can't find the cause of. In Linux, this is because `hashmap[0] is NULL`, and hence `hashmap[0]->first` can't even be accessed in the first place. But on Windows, it clearly shows that hashmap[0] exists and has an initialised `first` value.

I don't know what is going on here, and I can't find anything regarding this bug. If more code is needed, everything is on my [github.](https://github.com/MasterTextman/c-tasks/blob/master/Task%202/hashmap.h) Linked to the actual file this code is in. But for now, I'm confused as to what's going on...

UPDATE: Apparently I had some looking up to do. Didn't know that malloc returned an uninitialized pointer and not just NULL. That was set by Linux. Thanks though, learnt something new today.

Comment: `malloc` does not have to initialise the allocated memory, although a particular implementation may do (to prevent peeking into recycled memory). You must always initialise it yourself. If you want to guarantee that the allocated memory will be set to `0` then use `calloc`.

Comment: what do you mean 'the BASES are initialized', your code doesnt even allocate any BASES

Comment: @WeatherVane That's my point. I don't want the allocated memory to be initialised, but for some reason on Windows it is being initialised.

Comment: @pm100 SPACE is an array of BASEs. hashmap is a struct of type SPACE *. When I say, initialized, I mean that the BASEs in hashmap are NOT NULL. On Linux, they are set to NULL, however on windows, they are not.

Comment: your `typedef`s are confusing me.. so `BASE` is a `struct base`, `SPACE` is a `BASE*`, so that means `SPACE*` is a `BASE**`? If `hashmap` is a `BASE**`, then you'll need to allocate memory for each `BASE*` before you can `hashmap[#]->` safely, where `#` is 0-2 if `length` is 3.

Comment: @yano Sorry for the confusion, it's because SPACE is meant to be an array of BASEs. And yes, I understand that, but I use code that uses stuff such as `if(hashmap[0])`. Basically my problem is that on Windows, hashmap[0] technically `exists`, but since there isn't memory allocated to it, `hashmap[0]->` still causes SIGSEGV.

By technically exists, I mean that it isn't explicitly NULL.

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with Linux or Windows. And no, they are not "set to NULL" on Linux, as you seem to believe. Your nulls are purely accidental.

Comment: If you have a double pointer, you have to go through 2 "rounds" of memory allocation. In the code you've shown, you've only done the first round. So if `length` is 3, then after what you've shown, accessing `hashmap[0,1,2]` is valid, however, accessing `hashmap[0,1,2]->` is not valid since you haven't allocated memory for each `BASE*` yet. You must loop over `length` and do `hashmap[i] = malloc(sizeof BASE);` first.

Comment: ok so you have it backwards. Linux has initialized the pointers to null. Windows has not, it has left random values. As other point out malloc is not required to initialize the memory it returns (cf. calloc). Most platforms do not. Sometimes it depends on whether you are running DEBUG build or not. You code should *always* assume that the memory is not initialized

Comment: @pm100 No, Linux did not initialize the pointers to NULL.  That just happened to be the value of the bytes returned.  The man page explicitly says the memory is not initialized.  Changing optimization settings could result in different values for the uninitialized bytes.

Comment: @dbush - i was wondering about that too. So in fact neither OS initialized, just different random values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values of bytes pointed to after a successfull call to `malloc` are uninitialized.  That means they can be set to any arbitrary value, including zero.  So just because the bytes are either zero or non-zero doesn't mean they are initialized.

Section 7.22.3.4 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) regarding `malloc` states:

> *1*
>
> ```
> #include <stdlib.h>
> void *malloc(size_t size);
> ```
>
> *2* The `malloc` function allocates space for an object whose size is specified by `size` **and whose value is indeterminate**.

So there are no guarantees what the memory returned by `malloc` will contain.

If on the other hand you use `calloc`, that function will initialize all allocated bytes to 0.

```
hashmap = calloc(length, sizeof(SPACE *));
```

Comment: The first parameter to `calloc` is the number of elements to allocate, and the second is the size of an element.

Comment: I'm guessing that it's best for me to replace any malloc associated with a struct that has pointers in it with calloc then, the first parameter being 1.

Comment: @txtman If you only want to allocate one instance of the struct, then yes.  If you want to allocate an array, then the first parameter is the length of the array.

Comment: For what purpose, @txtman?  Your problem is not that the initial contents of the allocated memory are nonzero, it is that you fail to set the contents to appropriate values after allocation.  Perhaps you are also making an incorrect assumption that non-NULL pointer values are necessarily valid.

Comment: Nono, I understand that non-NULL doesn't necessarily mean valid now. It's just that I have many checks within my code that check whether a certain struct is set to NULL. For example if I do `SPACE *hey = malloc(something)` I have checks like `if(hey[0])`.

Answer (score 2):

> Let's say that length is 3. In Linux, when I check the debugger, I see
>   that:
>
> ```
> hashmap[0] = NULL;
> hashmap[1] = NULL;
> hashmap[2] = NULL;
> ```
>
> Because I did not initialise the BASEs, I only initialised the fact
>   that there is an array of them.

No.  You get all of those being `NULL` because that happens to be what you get.  C does not specify the initial contents of the memory returned by `malloc()`, and if you performed that allocation under other circumstances then you might not get all NULLs.

> However, in Windows, I see that all of
>   the BASES are initialised. Not only that, but all of the ITEMs within
>   the BASEs are initialised as well.

They may have non-NULL values, but that's very different from being initialized.  The values are very likely to be wild pointers.  If they happen to point to accessible memory then you can interpret the data where they point as `ITEM`s, but again, that does not mean they are initialized, or that it is safe to access that memory.  You are delving into undefined behavior here.

> However, if I, for example, immediately afterwards add this line:
>   hashmap[0]->first = NULL, I end up with a SIGSEGV error that I can't
>   find the cause of.

We can't speak to the cause of your segmentation fault because you have not presented the code responsible, but having an array of pointers does not mean the pointer values within are valid.  If they are not, then dereferencing them produces undefined behavior, which often manifests as a segfault.  Note well that this does not depend on those pointers being `NULL`; it can attend accessing *any* pointer value that does not point to an object belonging to your program and having compatible type.

> In Linux, this is because hashmap[0] is NULL, and
>   hence hashmap[0]->first can't even be accessed in the first place. But
>   on Windows, it clearly shows that hashmap[0] exists and has an
>   initialised first value.

No, it doesn't.  Again, your debugger shows `hashmap[0]` having a *non-`NULL`* value, which is not at all the same thing.

It is your responsibility to avoid dereferencing invalid pointer values, which are by no means limited to `NULL`.

Comment: I was wrong then... I thought that anything that wasn't `NULL` was initialised. Excuse me, I only just started learning C, but thank you. The problem is that I have a lot of code that has stuff such as `if(hashmap[0])`. When it isn't NULL, that returns as true, which is where my problem comes. But thank you.

Comment: Didn't know that it was Linux that sets the return value of malloc to NULL though, that's definitely helpful.

Comment: No, @txtman, it's not.  You cannot rely on that behavior on Linux, or anywhere else.

Comment: I know, I know. But our lecturer and my past (by past I mean a month ago) experience with C on Linux made me think that malloc returns NULL.

Comment: @txtman `malloc` returns NULL (that is, the function return value of `malloc`) if it fails to provide a memory chunk with the size you requested. You should absolutely check this every time you call `malloc` (or `calloc`). If `malloc` returns non-NULL, then it returns a valid pointer to a memory chunk with usable size that you have requested. However, `malloc` does nothing to the memory chunk itself.